# Getting duplicate fingerprint error while updating SHA-1 fingerprint for Android oAuth2 Client ID

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console, clientid

Just a few days ago I have changed my SHA-1 fingerprint (from signing to dev) for testing purpose. Now I want to go back to signing SHA-1 but it's not allowing me to add live SHA-1 fingerprint. It gives me `duplicate fingerprint error`.

I am sure that we do not have any other client id already registered with the app's fingerprint. We don't have any deleted project as well. My app is already in the Store I can't simply change the package or the keystore to make it work.

While updating `SHA-1` fingerprint in the Google Cloud Platform developer console, I get the following popup:

> Duplicate fingerprint
>
> The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project

---

Anyone with a similar problem that managed to reach a solution?

Comment: You are going to register your one Project with multiple Google cloud projects with same package name and applicationId. Make another app on Google Cloud or do some changing in your package name and create SHA1 again.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**I found a fix to this problem.**

When the console asks you for the SHA1 and Package name for a new API that you are using in the same app.

Just keep the same SHA1 code and change the Package name a little.
Eg: com.example.exampleapp to com.example.exampleapp**1** .

I know this is not a full proof solution but i have many different google API calls in my app by just changing the package name a little.

I tried many solution from [This](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554) but my simple fix helped me move on.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This solution requires you to change the package name

Answer (score 4):

#### You have to go to your API console and undelete your old project that contains the OAuth ID that you are trying to use for your new project.

```
One of the previous projects that I had already deleted still contained it.
```

- You couldn't add the new `OAuth` because it "already existed" even though your project did not contain that ID already.

When you delete a project in the API console, the `OAuth` IDs associated with it seem to not get deleted with it.

<sup>**This should really be changed!**</sup>